# Master Slave communication through RS485

Tags: c++, arduino-uno

I ordered a sensor that measures three parameters at specific register addresses. The sensor uses a modbus protocol for communication (RS 485). I use the arduino as master and the sensor as slave. Since I don't have the sensor yet, there is a software (Modsim32) running on my windows 10 computer that allows me to simulate a Slave. I would like to make my arduino communicate with the simulation software through the RS485 using the Modbus RTU protocol.
when a run the program based on ModbusMaster library I find in the serial port a 226, according to what i had read that is a error message. But why?
l am using an arduino Uno The communication is done through the RS485 and a USB port.
[image]

RS485 :DollaTek 5PCS 5V MAX485 / RS485 Modul TTL zu RS-485 MCU Entwicklungsboard
USB: WINGONEER CH340E USB zu TTL USB zu RS485 Konverter Adapter Windows 7/8 XP Linux Vista
Here is my code:

```
#include <ModbusMaster.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
/*!
  We're using a MAX485-compatible RS485 Transceiver.
  Rx/Tx is hooked up to the hardware serial port at 'Serial'.
  The Data Enable and Receiver Enable pins are hooked up as follows:
*/
#define MAX485_DE      3
#define MAX485_RE_NEG  2

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 20, 4);

// instantiate ModbusMaster object
ModbusMaster node;

void preTransmission()
{
  digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 1);
  digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 1);
}

void postTransmission()
{
  digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 0);
  digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 0);
}

void setup()

{
  // Modbus communication runs at 115200 baud
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Modbus slave ID 10
  node.begin(10, Serial);

  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();

  pinMode(MAX485_RE_NEG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MAX485_DE, OUTPUT);
  // Init in receive mode
  digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 0);
  digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 0);


  // Callbacks allow us to configure the RS485 transceiver correctly
  node.preTransmission(preTransmission);
  node.postTransmission(postTransmission);
}



void loop()
{
  uint8_t result;

  // Read 1 registers starting at 0x3100)
  result = node.readInputRegisters(0x3100, 1);   // I am getting 226 here

  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(result);

  /*  if (result == node.ku8MBSuccess)
    {
      Serial.print("Vbatt: ");
      Serial.println(node.getResponseBuffer(0x04)/100.0f);
      Serial.print("Vload: ");
      Serial.println(node.getResponseBuffer(0xC0)/100.0f);
      Serial.print("Pload: ");
      Serial.println((node.getResponseBuffer(0x0D) +
                      node.getResponseBuffer(0x0E) << 16)/100.0f);
    }*/

  delay(1000);
}
```

Does anyone has an idea about this Problem?

Here you can see a picture of the Slave simulation software

[image]